# How to test Subversion functions?

Tags: c#, svn, unit-testing, mono

I am implementing an [application](http://code.google.com/p/subsynct/) that involves some svn functions.

I'm gonna write some unit tests for the app, however, how would you suggest I write unit tests for svn commands such as checkout, update, status, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, what to test or how to implement the actual testing in your framework / testing platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your SVN-specific code within a class, implementing an interface. When unit testing your main application, stub/fake/mock/whatever your SVN class via the interface. You can then unit test most of your application this way.

Testing the actual SVN interaction will not be a unit test, but rather an integration test. You can write your test cases directly to your SVN implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You could:

- Use a stub instead of the real `svn` command; the stub could log its invocations and, at the end of the test, you can check that `svn` has been invoked as you intended (this is more like a [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) than a stub).
- Create a "sandbox" repository in a temporary directory and perform actual operations on it, like I did in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252375/svn-source-control-issues-when-merging-changes/2253589#2253589).